# I raised my cat since she was born and now she doesn't like me?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology

I once startled a cat at this abandoned house and then when it ran off, a kitten popped up who I think was just born. I ended up keeping it and took care of her and named her Sam.

She loved me, she would follow me everywhere and would even go to sleep with me when I went to bed. Then when she hit the age of (I think) 2 she started to not come in my room as often, and wouldn't love me as much. Then, all of a sudden she started sleeping with my 13 year old brother, like what has he ever done for you? I thought it was because she likes his room for some reason, but wherever he goes to sleep she's right there sleeping with him. She follows him everywhere.

She's my baby girl and she doesn't even love me. I'm heartbroken. I'm just wondering, is there any reason she would become unattached from me and all of a sudden attached to my brother?

As an additional note - she has been spayed.

Comment: Cats are notoriously fickle and “moody.” Has she been eating well, drinking normally? Has she been more aggressive? Have you noticed any other behaviors besides her apathy toward you? How does she behave with your brother?

Comment: When she comes to sleep with you, to you pet her, hug her, or anythign like that? Perhaos she just feels you don't give her space, and your brother is a warm human, too, and may just let her be when nearby!

Comment: Note that it's possible you're being *too* affectionate for her mood, so she is seeking out someone who wont bother her when she's trying to sleep, just provide a warm, comfy pillow. Try ignoring her for a while, if that's what your brother does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cats are extremely moody creatures however they don't stop loving someone out of nowhere randomly. Chances are you accidentally offended your cat and now she is trying to make you jealous. Me and my friend also have a cat and whenever one of us slight him he starts to act all loving to the other one especially while the offender is looking at him.

In order to regain her love you can either try to act as normally as possible and eventually your cat will forget you slighted her or just decide making you jealous is no longer an option and return to you.

If you want a faster solution try to give her attention from afar through actions like putting premium cat food in her food bin and sitting next to her without touching her. Remember to never touch her unless she acts first asking for a petting and she should return to loving you within a week or two.